# DatabaseException(incomplete input (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR) in Flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter

When I am using flutter and creating table, I get the following error! :

```
error DatabaseException(incomplete input (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE scheduled_shift_groups(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, uniqueGroupId TEXT, nightShiftCount INTEGER, dayShiftCount INTEGER, weekEnding INTEGER, estimatedIncome REAL) sql 'CREATE TABLE scheduled_shift_groups(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, uniqueGroupId TEXT, nightShiftCount INTEGER, dayShiftCount INTEGER, weekEnding INTEGER, estimatedIncome REAL' args []} during open, closing...
```

Here is my code:

```
 Future<Database> database = getDatabasesPath().then((String path) {
    return openDatabase(
      join(path, dbName),
      onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
        await db.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE $scheduledShiftGroupsTableName(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, uniqueGroupId TEXT, nightShiftCount INTEGER, dayShiftCount INTEGER, weekEnding INTEGER, estimatedIncome REAL");
      },
      version: 1,
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 24):

Actually, I made a stupid mistake!!! in the execute method I forgot `)` sign after `REAL`.

Now Problem solved). Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it. You saved some important hours.

Comment: Seriously... I wonder I made same mistake

Comment: crazily simple error which wastes hours;)

Comment: life saverrrrrrrrrrrrrr.....:)